# How to locate all unused Lisp functions / variables

Tags: refactoring

I am converting a few old libraries into one new library using different names for all of the functions, macros, variables, etc.  Some of the functions / variables will never be used, and I would like to eliminate those unused functions / variables.  Other than grepping each item one by one to see whether it is referenced somewhere within other Lisp libraries that will be using the new definitions, or haphazardly / randomly commenting stuff out and restarting Emacs (to see if it complains of missing stuff), is there a more efficient method of obtaining a list of unused functions / variables?

By analogy, when building Emacs from source, I can use the `-Wall` `CFLAGS` and see stuff that is unused:  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: In principle that's hard to do with total confidence, because you could have `(funcall (intern (concat prefix "-" suffix)))` and be awfully unlikely to detect which function it's calling without running the code.  In practice you're probably pretty safe looking for the names as defined.  I don't have an answer -- I'd just grep (albeit not "one by one"... `grep -f <file>` is probably your friend here).

Comment: In an Emacs Lisp library, all functions and variables are public, user can use some or none of them, how can we know whether a function or variable should be removed? let's say we have 3 variables, a=1, b=2, and c=b+1, since a is not used, we remove it, and c is also not used, we remove it, in the end, b is also not used and we remove all of them?

Comment: @xuchunyang Private functions and variables are marked by starting their names with PREFIX-- (two dashes)